# CSS for Slideshow box with images and captions

Tags: html, css, styling

I was about to make a Slideshow for a website I'm currently working on, but I'm stuck at the styling/layout. I know that there already are Slideshows read-to-use online, but I wanted to make my own clean and simple one.

The images are planned to be moved from right to left, not a fade effect. I'm also willing to use a little JS, to keep the CSS cleaner (CSS transitions will be used though).

My current status: https://jsfiddle.net/8c3ods5o/

This seems to work as-is (not really tested though), but I need captions under the image as well. My first thought to accomplish this, fails bad though: https://jsfiddle.net/8c3ods5o/2/

```css
.slider {
    max-width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .img-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.slider .img-wrapper > div {
    position: relative;
}

.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slider .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="screenshots slider">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/">
            <span class="caption">some caption text</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/">
            <span class="caption">another caption..</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/">
            <span class="caption">another caption..</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/">
            <span class="caption">another caption..</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you use bootstrap on your webpage?

Comment: Nope. Only [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: Ok, I've found a simple solution myself. I just need to give the img-wrapper a `width: 400%;`. Not an ideal solution if the amount of images in the slider is variable, but in my case that's a constant. :)

Comment: or you could calculate the width once the images are loaded with easy jquery intruction and apply to css.